# Plotting facetgrid in subplot for IRIS dataset

Tags: python, visualization, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot 6 selected pair subplots with the combination of **facetgrid** of seaborn and **scatter plot** from matplotlib.
I'm getting plot, but subplots remains empty whereas facetgrid gets plotted in a new figure.

Below is my code-

```
pairs = [["SepalLengthCm", "SepalWidthCm"], ["PetalLengthCm", "PetalWidthCm"], ["SepalLengthCm", "PetalWidthCm"], ["PetalLengthCm", "SepalWidthCm"], ["PetalLengthCm", "SepalLengthCm"], ["PetalWidthCm", "SepalWidthCm"]]
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
i = 1
for each in pairs:
    plt.subplot(2,3,i)
    sns.set_style("whitegrid")
    fg = sns.FacetGrid(iris, hue="Species", size=4)
    fg.map(plt.scatter,each[0], each[1]).add_legend();
    plt.show()
    i += 1
```

Sample Output:

[image]

Can someone help out with it?